# Go - strange json hyphen unmarshall error

Tags: json, go

I am having a very strange error while working with a json string. The problem was first introduced when I added a key-value pair of strings to the json input, which was `"DeviceIdentifier": "device-id"`. I pared down my code to the minimum necessary to display the error. The error disappears when I change pretty much anything about the data in that key-value pair, which seems very strange to me. I can just use other keys to circumvent the error, but it seems like there is something I am missing here. Either that or there would seem to be something wrong with the library function... Any ideas?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type S struct {
    Name            string
    DeviceIdentifier []byte
}

func main() {
    var s S

    data := []byte(`{"Name": "test", "DeviceIdentifier": "device-id"}`)

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```

Go playground link: http://play.golang.org/p/huXuaokGik

Json package documentation: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

**UPDATE**

I just discovered that the encoding succeeds when the value string has a length that is divisible by 4, e.g. `abcd` and `abcdefgh` work, while `abcde` and abcdefg` do not.

Now that I know what base64 strings are the error makes a lot of sense. References here:

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Conversion tool: http://www.string-functions.com/base64encode.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [json package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) documentation :

> Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, except that []byte
>   encodes as a base64-encoded string, and a nil slice encodes as the
>   null JSON object.

so if you change your structure to `DeviceIdentifier string` it will work

[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1M899l98kD)

Comment: ...and `-` is not a valid character in a base64 encoded string. So, as `Unmarshal` comes to a byte slice and attempts to unencode it (assuming its base64), it will fail.

Comment: Using a string is a valid fix for the issue, but it is inconvenient for me elsewhere in the app because I will have to do casting, which is fine but just a little messy looking. I read some stuff like that about hyphens, but I can reproduce the error without hyphens as well: http://play.golang.org/p/0zbUj5yuO9 leading me to think that the issue is deeper than that.

Comment: Per my update above, the base64 encoded string issue was indeed the root of the problem. I implemented that encoding on the client side and it solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to note another possibility, in order to keep the struct field as a `[]byte`, it also works perfectly well to just actually do the base64 encoding on the client side so that the value passed through the json represents something valid in base64. This was the solution I ended up using in my project. The `json.Marshal()` function in Go does this automatically for structs that contain a byte slice.